# Use JAR file containing only Java source files on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have few JAR files which have only Java source code (.java) files and not the byte code (.class) files.

How can I include these JAR files as dependencies in my Eclipse project?

I tried adding these to the classpath but that's not working. I don't want to inflate each JAR file in my project, I just want to reference them.

Comment: You need to add the corresponding jar file with .class files to your class path, and then you can add the jar with source files as the "Java Source Attachment" for that .class jar file.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but without the .class files in the jar, these jar files having the source code cannot be used. correct?

Comment: That's correct, you need the compiled .class files in the JAR you depend on. The JAR with the source .java files is just for you to reference.

Comment: @ManikVij Yes that's how they're intended to be used. If you want to compile from source, you're better off getting the source distribution, since that will include all artifacts necessary to compile - which a source jar would not.

Comment: Corrected grammar and formatting.

Comment: @ Erwin Bolwidt @matt Thanks for the update and clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Better to download jar with .class but still if you want to create jar then ...
Extract the jar file with source code.
put all the java classes in same directory.

Compile it with following command so package will be created.

```
javac -d . *.java
```

Make zip file using following command

```
jar -cf JarFileNameHere.jar listof all packages and classes
```

Then you can use that jar file.

Comment: This won't work if the source has dependencies on other jar files which are handled by maven/gradle/etc.

Comment: Yes,  I know that,  I told for  normal case you can go fir it. :) :)